Serialization of Class's in C# into an XML file
I want to serialize the class 'kyerocontent' but only it's content (kyero and property classes), so on the XML file generated, it doesn't appear "kyerocontent" as an element.
public async Task<string> GenerateKyeroXml(UserModel user, List<ProductFields> properties)
{
    // Initialize the list to hold individual XML strings for each property
    List<string> kyeroList = new List<string>();

    // Foreach to transform each property to XML
    properties.ForEach(property =>
    {
        // Transform the property to XML
        var propertyobject = new Kyero.kyerocontent();

        propertyobject.Property = new Kyero.property
        {
            id = property?.Id, //verificar?
            reference = GetValueOrNull(property?.Code)?.ToString(),//property61(está sempre null?) ou será name/code?
            currency = GetValueOrNull(property?.PurchasingCurrency),
            date = GetValueOrNull(property.DateCreate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), //verificar
            price = Convert.ToDecimal(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property70")?.ToString().Split("|")[0]), //verificar o 160000|EUR
            type = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property60")?.ToString(),//verificar "house" "land" etc...
            province = null, //Algarve
            country = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property302")?.ToString(),
            price_freq = null, //verificar sale/rent/etc
            town = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property305")?.ToString(),
            //status = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property69")?.ToString(),
            beds = ConvertToNullableInt(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property75")),
            baths = ConvertToNullableInt(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property76")),
            pool = ConvertYNTo01(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property79").ToString()), //verificar?
            //images = new List<Kyero.XMLImageUrl>
            //{
            //    new Kyero.XMLImageUrl
            //    {
            //        ID = imageCounter,
            //        url =GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property303")?.ToString(),
            //    },
            //},
            energyrating = new EnergyRating
            {
                consumption = ConvertConsumption(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property83")?.ToString()),
            },
            surfacearea = new SurfaceArea
            {
                built = ConvertToNullableInt(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property77")),
                plot = ConvertToNullableInt(GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property78")),
            },
            desc = new XMLDescList
            {
                PT = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property307")?.ToString(),
                EN = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property308")?.ToString(),
                FR = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property309")?.ToString(),
                DE = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property310")?.ToString(),
                NL = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property311")?.ToString(),
                SV = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property312")?.ToString(),
                RU = GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property313")?.ToString(),
            },
            features = new List<string>
        {
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property279")?.ToString(),
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property280")?.ToString(),
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property281")?.ToString(),
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property282")?.ToString(),
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property283")?.ToString(),
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property284")?.ToString(),
            GetValueFromDictionary(property.CustomFields, "property285")?.ToString(),
        }
            .Where(feature => feature != null)
            .ToList(),
        };

        // Serialize the individual property to XML and add it to the list
        string propertyString = SerializeToXml(property);
        kyeroList.Add(propertyString);
    });

    var kyeroobject = new kyero
    {
        feed_version = "3",
    };
    string kyeroString = SerializeToXml(kyeroobject);
    kyeroList.Insert(0, kyeroString);

    // Join all the individual XML strings into one string
    string combinedkyero = string.Join("\n", kyeroList);

    // Wrap the combined XML content within a root element
    string kyeroWithRoot = $"<root>{"\n" + combinedkyero}\n</root>";

    // Write the combined XML string to a file
    string filePath = "KyeroXML.xml";
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(filePath, kyeroWithRoot);

    // Return the file path
    return filePath;
}

private string SerializeToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true
        };

        // Create XmlWriter with settings
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
        {
            // Create XmlSerializerNamespaces and set it to null to avoid serializing namespaces
            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = null;

            // Serialize the object
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, namespaces);
        }

        // Convert the serialized data to string
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}

This is my code. I want to return every strings that it finds me on a list, which in case is this 'combinedkyero' but without the 'kyerocontent'.
public class kyerocontent
{
    [XmlElement("kyero")]
    public kyero Kyero { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("property")]
    public property Property { get; set; }
}
public class kyero
{
    [XmlElement("feed_version")]
    public string? feed_version { get; set; }
}

public class property
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int? id { get; set; }
   
    (Rest of the property elements)
}

Example of the XML file should be:
<root>
  <kyero>
    <feed_version>3</feed_version>
  </kyero>
  <property>
    <id>4625</id>
    <!-- rest of the property elements -->
  </property>
</root>


Is there a specific reason why you don't use attributes to control XML serialization? Using XmlIgnoreAttribute should give you full control to supress unwanted properties.

I'm new to coding, i'm currently on an internship so I don't know very much xD. I want my file xml file to be looking like this:


<feed_version> feedversioncontent </feed_version>


 idcontent 



Basically I'm doing it the way they told me and the way chatgpt majorily told me xD. Is there any tip in how I can manage the classes without changing much of the code?
I have elements and attributes in other situations and I have the same issue.

Can you please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] of your kyero class and it's properties and the desired Xml output?

I'm trying but idk it isn't letting me edit my question.

Click the Edit link under your question.

I'm putting now the xml file output as an example, It wasn'tl letting me edit properly idk why.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638292/create-delete-element-on-xmlnode-c-sharp/73640395#73640395, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72587699/too-many-xml-in-one-xml-file/72589790#72589790, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68510288/edit-tag-parameter-in-xml-using-vb-net/68513150#68513150 (VB.NET, but contains a good explanation).

I'll try to have a look to see if it helps and if I can understand something, ty for the feedback !
